# How can I transfer audio buffer to play it directly

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I tried to create an Audio buffer and send him to a new class.
In this Class I would play this buffer with AudioTracker but it doesn't work.
I can hear the sound on time but the sound is like a halleffect. I have no Idear for my mistake and didn't found an answer for this problem .
I hope you can help me.
(Sorry my English is not the best)
Sorcecode:

```
public class input {
private static final String TAG = "Aufnahme";
private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;
private int SAMPLERATE = 8000;
private int CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
private int AUDIO_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLERATE, CHANNELS,
        AUDIO_FORMAT);
private Thread recordingThread = null;

public void startRecording() {
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLERATE,
            CHANNELS, AUDIO_FORMAT, bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable()

    {
        public void run() {
            writeAudioData();
        }

    });
    recordingThread.start();

}

public void stopRecording() {
    isRecording = false;
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder = null;
    recordingThread = null;
}

private void writeAudioData() {

    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];

    while (isRecording) {

        recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
        send(data);

    }
}

private void send(byte[] data) {

    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    at.play();
    at.write(data, 0, bufferSize);
    at.stop();
    at.release();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured out the problem. The hall effect came from the speaker sound which was recorded in real time. Bad mistake.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: I played around with the bufferSize and minbufferSize and was able to get faithful playback of the audio data. I fixed the input buffer to 8192 and output to 1024. It can be tweaked further but it serves my purpose. Thanks for the original code. It works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The reason when you write data to `AudioTrack` object, you actually open it, write to buffer, close and release it, and if the minimum buffer size is so small, you cannot actually hear because of constant re-initilization of the AudioTrack. This is why it is solved by changing the buffer size. If you make it 8000 and your sample rate is 8000, you will hear the sound with one second delay. To solve this, get rid of your send method and change the writeAudio method to this:

private void writeAudioData() {
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];

```
    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


    at.play();

    while (isRecording) {
        recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
        at.write(data, 0, bufferSize);
    }
    at.stop();
    at.release();
```